# Creating a log scale graph in MatLab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot a simple graph that shows the relationship of real numbers on the `x` axis to the `log` numbers on the `y` axis.  My graph is close, but not what I expected.  My vector starts at `1` and ends at `100`.  I figured that `1` would equal `10^0`, `2` equal `10^0.3`, right up to `100` being equal to `10^2`.

My code:

```
x = log10(1:100);
plot(x)
set(gca,'YScale','log')
grid on
```

My graph:

[image: log]

Comment: You did not ask a question. What is it that you are trying to get?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it worked. As you say, `10^0.3 = 2`, which is the top index on your `semilogy` plot. What your plot here actually shows is `y=log10(log10(x));`. Leave the y-axis linear and you will get the plot you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I must be missing something as to me number 2 on the x axis (between 0 -10) is `10^-0.5` right on the bottom os the `y` axis.  `100` should be on `10^2`, but my data doesn't get know where near that high in the graph.

Comment: I've just discovered without the line of code `set(gca, 'YScale', 'log')` it is indeed correct with 2 being the top of the index of `y`.  As soon as I set the `gca` it treats the top index number `2` as: what is the `log10(2)` which is not what I want to see.

Comment: log10(log10(2)) = -0.52, log10(log10(100)) = +0.30, your y axis goes from 10^-0.52 to 10^+0.30.